Two nouns going with one article with a specific concern: Malaysia had **a much higher birth rate** and **growth rate**
Considering this pair of sentences, I think:


I have a dog and a cat. => correct
I have a dog and cat. => incorrect


What about these two?


Malaysia had a much higher birth rate and growth rate.

Malaysia had a much higher birth rate and a much higher growth rate.



Sentence 4 is obviously grammatical, but what about sentence 3? It's more concise and sounds right to me; however, can birth rate and growth rate go with only one article a? When I think about sentence 2, which is (to me) obviously incorrect, I doubt if sentence 3 is correct since it's pretty similar to sentence 2.
If sentence 3 is incorrect, how can I make sentence 4 more concise?

Even if it is grammatical (i.e. those who say it are numerous enough and those who balk at it are few enough) it isn't clear why you're linking them like that, so why even go down that path?  Malaysia's birth rate and growth rate were both much higher than _____.

I don't know which grammatical authorities consider "a dog and cat" to be incorrect, but not everybody has a problem with it, and there are plenty of real-world examples. "a much higher birth rate and growth rate" doesn't sound wrong to me, but it's a bit inelegant and I'd prefer TimR's alternative.

I have a son and daughter. I have an aunt and uncle. I have a car, moped, and bicycle. Why do you think these are wrong? You can usually omit second and subsequent articles if no ambiguity results.

@TimR The full sentence is: "Despite having a smaller population size in 1980, Malaysia had a much higher birth rate and growth rate." When I was writing it, I thought the second clause's subject should be the same as the first clause's, as this is a sentence with a reduced adverbial clause. I'm not so sure about this, though. Your suggestion indeed sounds better, but is it till correct going wth the first half of the sentence?

Regarding "I have a dog and cat", I've read on some forum that it should be "and a cat", and in my experience, I rarely hear the first version. But of course, native speakers' words are more accurate, so thanks for pointing out that it's not actually ungrammatical.

FWIW, I would always include the second 'a' (but I also prefer Tim's version).

Higher than what?   What is the comparand?

@TimR higher than Australia's birth rate and growth rate. I'm comparing these two countries' demographic information.

Sentence 3 is perfectly understandable and most people would not think about the grammar. For an English class assessment you might like Malaysia had much higher birth and growth rates.

The reason to avoid "a x and y" is that it is clumsy, and clumsiness in writing interferes with the streamlined delivery of information to the reader, just as clumsiness of motion when running places undue stresses on the body, causing it to tire.

In the example you provided for comparison of "I have a dog and cat", both articles are completely necessary because a function of the indefinite article is to denote the number one. It means "I have one dog and one cat". You could not say "I have dog and cat" because dog and cat are countable nouns. If two nouns are naturally combined, ie they come as a pair like "a knife and fork", then it is normal to refer to the combination with one article, but "dog and cat" is not such a combination.
"Birth rate" and "growth rate" however are not inherently countable - they are abstract nouns. When referring to them as general concepts, they don't even need articles. For example, you could say "Birth rate is a key indicator of population growth".
However, like many non-countable nouns, they can become countable and require articles when referring to specific instances. You could say that every country has 'a' birth rate, but when speaking about a particular country's birth rate it would be the only one, so you would say "the birth rate in Malaysia".
In your example, the sentence is comparative. "A much higher birth rate" refers to a specific instance or level of birth rate that Malaysia had, compared to its growth rate. The article is necessary because, when you use a comparative adjective (like "higher") along with a qualifier (like "much"), you're referring to a specific instance or degree of the noun—in this case, a specific level of birth rate that is "much higher" than something else. But there is no need to repeat the article for the second item because, as we have established, it does not require one and you are not repeating the comparative adjective.

Thanks for your answer, Astralbee. "both articles are completely necessary" => so you disagree with those who say that "I need a cat and dog" is also acceptable? I didn't expect that it's a matter of opinion in this regard.

@AnIELTSLearner I would not say "I need a cat and dog". "Cat and dog" is not a recognised, compound noun, like "knife and fork" is, for example. But cats and dogs are not normally grouped together in a combination like that so it just doesn't sound natural. The fact you can say "I need a knife and fork" means that your example isn't grammatically unsound, but grammar isn't everything - it isn't idiomatic, it sounds odd.
